# Use Third Party Routing Library in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 comes with angular/router package.

Instead of `import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';`

I want to use other routing library. Is it possible to use another library?

Comment: Why would you use another library for routing ?

Comment: I find it big in size. 63 kb in bundle size.

Comment: even with a 512Kb connection, you would download it in less than a tenth of a second. And it's cached afterwards. I understand your concern, but this is probably the best way to route an application (and after a quick serach, I haven't found anything). Besides, who says if you find another package, it will be lighter than this one ?

Comment: What library are you wanting to use?

Comment: Any other library like PATHJS